# python telnet function with __main__ global name is not defined

Tags: python, function, global, program-entry-point

I'm newbie of using python. I'm going to write a simple telnet program but stack in place.

**telnet.py**

```
def pingfunc():
    global domainname
    host  = "1.1.1.1"
    user  = "user1"
    password = "password2"
    telnet  = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
    telnet.read_until('Username: ', 3)
    telnet.write(user + '\r')
    telnet.read_until('Password: ', 3)
    telnet.write(password + '\r')
    telnet.write("ping " +  domainname + "\r\n")
    time.sleep(3)
    print telnet.read_very_eager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global domainname
    query_string = cgi.parse_qs(os.environ['QUERY_STRING'])
    domainname = query_string.get('domainname', ["www.google.com"])[0]
    count = query_string.get('count', [COUNT])[0]
```

when I call the function (pingfunc), the following error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   
telnet.write("ping " +  domainname + "\r\n")   
NameError: global name 'domainname' is not defined
```

May you help for this case?

Answer (score 3):

You're using the variable `domainname` in function `pingfunc()` without declaring it before (or passing it to the function as an argument).

Assuming `domainname` is already defined when you're calling the function, simply change the function signature.

Change the line:

```
def pingfunc():
```

with:

```
def pingfunc(domainname):
```

and when you call the function, pass `domainname` as an argument.

Comment: Thanks alfasin, I tried to place "global domainname" in pingfunc() but it doesn't work, can you guide me? Thanks

Comment: @marcohk if you have `domainname` already defined, simply pass it to the function as an argument: `def pingfunc(domainname):...` see example above

Comment: @marcohk: if you don't have a global variable, that obviously won't work.

Comment: @alfasin, when change it as def pingfunc(domainname):, Internal Server Error 500, I'm not sure what problem

Comment: it seems that the telnet function can not accept url while using "def pingfunc(domainname):, the output error change to pingfunc(8.8.8.8)SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Regarding telnet, 500 is Syntax error not server error. You can't pass a url to telnet: pass either an IP or dns-name. So try: `pingfunc('8.8.8.8')`.